# getUserMedia.js not detecting camera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently hoping to use a getUserMedia (HTML5) tool to create webcam accessible site. The tool found [here](https://github.com/addyosmani/getUserMedia.js). It's supposed to use HTML5 to get webcam access, but has a flash fallback for non supported browsers. But when I download it and open the demo locally on my computer I get the error: "JavaScript Alert: No camera available." But when I use the web demo found [here](http://addyosmani.github.io/getUserMedia.js/face-detection-demo/index.html). Anyone have an ideas on where I may have gone wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The web demo worked fine for me and I'm using Chrome:

- Do you have a camera on your device? That's a simple reason why it wouldn't work.
- Which browser are you using? Is the tool compatible with the your browser? see below for explanation.
- Are you running this on from file? Perhaps (I'm really only guessing) `navigator` variable doesn't work when loading from file

It probably got this error after it tried accessing your camera when calling the `navigator.getUserMedia()` function, which is what that tool uses.
I made that function compatable by defining the function to be:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
```

This is only compatible on Chrome and Firefox (and one other browser which I forgot) but, according to what I've seen recently, not on IE.

Good Luck!